# Class object array used within a class

Tags: c++, class

I am trying to create a deck of cards by creating a "card deck" class which uses an array of 52 "card" class objects. The array needs to be dynamically allocated, but I can't figure out the syntax to create this. My code gives this error:

> error C2512: 'Card' : no appropriate default constructor available

```
#include "CardDeck.h" 
#include "Card.h"
#include <iostream>      
#include <cstdlib>       
using namespace std;

CardDeck::CardDeck()
{

    *Deck = new Card[52];

}
```

I am curious as to whether I am able to create the array using my 
Card::Card(char a , char b) constructor, or if I must first create the array using a default constructor.

Comment: `'Card' : no appropriate default constructor available` - this means you don't have a constructor of the form `Card::Card()`.

Comment: Wow, for starters you definitely should not be including Card.cpp

Comment: *"error C2512: 'Card' : no appropriate default constructor available"* - hmm... what could that cryptic error possibly mean?

Comment: it seems like your Card class do not have a constructor Card(). Please include declaration of class Card also.

Comment: Whoops. I should have mentioned that the card class I want to use uses two char parameters. I'm just not sure the syntax of how to write this.

Comment: @user2105982 in traditional C++ is not possible to dynamically allocate an array with a non-default constructor. Allocate the array first, give the cards values after.

Answer (score 2):

To create an array of cards like that `Card` must have a default constructor

```
class Card
{
public:
    Card(); // default cosntructor
    ...
};
```

The reason is that a default constructor is needed to give the initial values to your array.

As juanchopanza says you should be using a vector instead, but you would still have the same problem.

As Ben says `#include "Card.cpp"` is also wrong.

Also this line looks suspicious

```
*Deck = new Card[52];
```

why are you dereferencing `Deck`? Almost certainly that is wrong too. I would show some more code. Seems you have quite a few errors.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't clear that it *has* to be dynamically allocated, but you can simplify the problem by using an `std::vector<card>` instead:

```
// CardDeck.h
#include <vector>

class CardDeck
{
 public:
  CardDeck() : deck_(52) {} // initialie deck_ to hold 52 cards
 private:
  std::vector<Card> deck_;
};
```

Don't forget to add [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) and do not include `.cpp` files.